# Android: WindowManager views count

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

In my application I add a `RelativeLayout` to the window (they're a banner sort). Occasionally there could be more than one `"banner"`, and so I want to count the number of views a.k.a `"banners"` inside the window, so I can set some `MarginTop` or sort to not let them overlap each other. Any idea?

```
private void initWindow() {
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mainNotificationFrameContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainNotificationFrame = new RelativeLayout(this);
    notificationDisplay = new TextView(this);
    notificationIcon = new ImageView(this);
    closeBannerButton = new ImageView(this);
    fadeInNotificationBanner = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in_notification_banner);
    fadeOutNotificationBanner = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out_notification_banner);

    setUpViews();

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams mainNotificationFrameContainerLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    mainNotificationFrameContainerLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    mainNotificationFrameContainerLayoutParams.y = 0;

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams mainNotificationFrameLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            150,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams notificationIconLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            150,
            150,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams closeNotificationBannerLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            150,
            150
    );

    closeNotificationBannerLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams notificationDisplayLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    notificationDisplayLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.notificationId);

    windowManager.addView(mainNotificationFrameContainer, mainNotificationFrameContainerLayoutParams);
    mainNotificationFrameContainer.addView(mainNotificationFrame, mainNotificationFrameLayoutParams);
    mainNotificationFrame.startAnimation(fadeInNotificationBanner);
    mainNotificationFrame.addView(notificationIcon, notificationIconLayoutParams);
    mainNotificationFrame.addView(notificationDisplay, notificationDisplayLayoutParams);
    mainNotificationFrame.addView(closeBannerButton, closeNotificationBannerLayoutParams);

    setUpListeners();
}
```

above is the function I used to add all the needed views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

Add one global `LinearLayout` and add the banners inside it, the `LinearLayout` has a method `getChildCount()`.

Extra pros: You don't need to do a "MarginTop" yourself!

I use this method for my app Tinycore on the Play Store

Comment: I actually already have a `LinearLayout` sitting behind the `RelativeLayout` which are the `"banners"`, but then they still overlap each other. Any idea?

Comment: Do you add the RelativeLayouts using the method addView?

Comment: Yes I do. With `LayoutParams` as well

Comment: You should post some of your code! Which View(s) do you add to the WindowManager?